# Double click instead of single click when to save files

Tags: pantheon-files

I'm an elementaryOS first timer, but been using Linux since 2001. I installed latest eOS yesterday but I found some difficulties, one of them is to set up 'double click'.

I've already set up to use double click on Files, but it won't work on a 'Save File' window.

When I try to save some files, I always double click folders to navigate folders, but if I double click, instead I will rewrite unintended file.